# Action: Move pointfeature to other layer - Point becomes Multipoint

Tags: pyqgis, point

I'm trying to write an action that moves a pointfeature from one layer to another. 
It works fine until i try to save the layer with the new feature on. He says he can't save a MULTIPOINT to a point-layer.

Any idea why it suddenly becomes a Multipoint?

I based this code on the following question: [How to create a QGIS action which copies features between layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74263/how-to-create-a-qgis-action-which-copies-features-between-layers)

Here is my code:

```
def getVectorLayerByName( layerName ): 
  layerMap = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers() 
  for name, layer in layerMap.iteritems(): 
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.name() == layerName: 
      if layer.isValid(): 
        return layer 
      else: 
        return None

iface = qgis.utils.iface
sourcelayer = getVectorLayerByName('plane')
iface.setActiveLayer(sourcelayer)
sourcelayer.startEditing()
iface.actionCutFeatures().trigger()
sourcelayer.commitChanges()
targetlayer = getVectorLayerByName('dots')
iface.setActiveLayer(targetlayer)
targetlayer.startEditing()
iface.actionPasteFeatures().trigger()
targetlayer.commitChanges()
```